# cannot find specific archetype

Tags: java, maven, dependencies, archetypes

i use maven and want to use jee5, but on mvn archetype:generate i cant find specific archetype, what should i do?

after i googling it i found 
   http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.mojo.archetypes/webapp-jee5/1.3

```
 <dependency>
<groupId>org.codehaus.mojo.archetypes</groupId>
<artifactId>webapp-jee5</artifactId>
<version>1.3</version>
```

is the only solution by adding jee5 depedency on pom.xml?, or any other way?

---

i found the reason, why i cant find jee5 after i did command mvn archetype:generate,
**because the CMD's screen buffer size height value is 300**

***here is the solution***
right click on CMD select default, then select  layout tab, change the value on Screen Buffer Size -> height

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the reason, why i cant find jee5 after i did command mvn archetype:generate,
**because the CMD's screen buffer size height value is 300**

***here is the solution***
right click on CMD select default, then select  layout tab, change the value on Screen Buffer Size -> height

Answer (score 0):

**webapp-jee5** is an archetype. It contains a prototype from wich generate your project structure. To do this you have to use the archetype plugin. Then you have to only run the following command

```
mvn archetype:generate  -DarchetypeGroupId=org.codehaus.mojo.archetypes -DarchetypeArtifactId=webapp-jee5 -DarchetypeVersion=1.3 -DgroupId=com.mycompany  -DartifactId=javaEE5App
```

this will create a project into directory where you run the command. Now the only thing is to import the project into your ide. For example in eclipse File->Import->Existing maven project

Comment: thanks dude^^, but i realize CMD has maximum character, so i tried to increase it (i put my explanation on above)